# LaTeX Error with large number of bibitems

Tags: bibliographies, errors, bibitem

Bibliography in my document 8POGL.tex is given with:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1099}

\bibitem{gadelhak} Gad-el-Hak, M., Ed., 2006, \textit{The MEMS Handbook - Introduction and Fundamentals}, Taylor \& Francis Group.
\bibitem{richard} Feynman, R. P., 1960, "There's Plenty of Room at the Bottom", Engineering and Science, \textbf{23}(5), pp. 22-36.
\bibitem{sandia-sajt} Sandia National Laboratories, n.d., http://mems.sandia.gov

\end{thebibliography}
```

It is shown only 3 items, but for real there is more than 100 items. Everything is working with small number of items (from 1 to around 30), but with all items I got error:

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{thebibliography} on input line 10 ended by \end{document}
.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.140 \end{document}
Your command was ignored.
Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,
or <return> to continue without it.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 140.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 140.
```

Where line 140 is in main document:

```
\begin{document}
\input{8POGL}
\end{document}  (line 140)
```

What should be solution of this, because there is no \end{document} anywhere in the bibliography? I am also confused because there is no error with smaller number of items?

Comment: What is line 10 in the bibliography? - To make sure that is is the number of items and not one special item: Did you try `\bibitem{AAgadelhak} AAGad-el-Hak, M., Ed., 2006, \textit{The MEMS Handbook - Introduction and Fundamentals}, Taylor \& Francis Group. \bibitem{ABgadelhak} ABGad-el-Hak, M., Ed., 2006, \textit{The MEMS Handbook - Introduction and Fundamentals}, Taylor \& Francis Group. \bibitem{ACgadelhak} ACGad-el-Hak, M., Ed., 2006, \textit{The MEMS Handbook - Introduction and Fundamentals}, Taylor \& Francis Group.` and so on and does that also work for, say, 29 items, but breaks for 30?

Comment: There were mistake in one bibitem, that made error (dont know yet exactly what, but that item was the problem).

Comment: always ask about the first error, if you choose to scroll past an error tex will try to recover but often generates more spurious errors